# pass parameter to PowerShell script when calling from Python

Tags: python, function, powershell, parameter-passing

From python I want to call a powershell script and pass a parameter to it

The Powershell function header is listed here:

```
Function Invoke-Neo4j
{
  [cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$false,ConfirmImpact='Low')]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,Position=0)]
    [string]$Command = ''
  )
```

Python - How do pass the parameter $Command = 'start' to the function from python? I can't seem to get it to work.

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['powershell.exe', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'RemoteSigned', '-File',
       'C:\\PathName\\Invoke-Neo4j.ps1']
returncode = subprocess.call(cmd)
print(returncode)
```

Comment: Your `.ps1` file define the function, but does it call it?

Comment: It did not call it. How would you call it? That's the part I'm struggling with

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make the Powershell command work from Python. I actually found a .bat file with a command that works. I just inserted the 'start' parameter I call the bat file from python. It works like a charm. It's not optimal but it does the job for me.

```
SETLOCAL
Powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "try { Unblock-File -Path '%~dp0Neo4j-Management\*.*' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' } catch {};Import-Module '%~dp0Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j 'start')"
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Answer (score 0):

Running a script, in either PowerShell or Python, that only defines a function but does not call it has no other effect than defining function. The script needs to include a specific call to that function. In your case, you might as well put the logic at the top level of the script instead of inside a function then calling the function. This would look like:

```
[cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$false,ConfirmImpact='Low')]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,Position=0)]
    [string]$Command = ''
)
# rest of code not surrounded by { }
exit 0
```

Invoke the revised script from Python as you were initially doing and it should work properly.